# HTML 5 url in angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc

Hi i was developed app using HashBang url in angularjs ,now i want to change it to HTML5 urls,want to remove # and with the help of this link https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag i done ...But Not working theng-view part not dispalying at all

Please help.

And This is my app.js

```
var blogbeatsApp = angular.module('blogbeatsApp', [ 'ngResource', 'ngRoute',
 'ngSanitize', 'ui.select', 'geolocation',
        'ui.bootstrap', 'decipher.tags', 'mgcrea.ngStrap', 'ui.growl',
        'angularFileUpload', 'ngTagsInput', 'ngMap', 'datatables']);

blogbeatsApp.config([ '$routeProvider','$locationProvider','$provide', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider,$provide) {
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'home',
        controller : 'HomeCtrl'
    }).when('/home', {
        templateUrl : 'home',
        controller : 'HomeCtrl'
    }).when('/dateBeats', {
        templateUrl : 'home/dateBeats',
        controller : 'DateSearchCtrl'
    }).when('/world', {
        templateUrl : 'home/world',
        controller : 'WorldCtrl'
    }).when('/curated', {
        templateUrl : 'home/curated',
        controller : 'CuratedCtrl'
    }).when('/careers', {
        templateUrl : 'careers/page',
        controller : 'CareersCtrl'
    }).when('/applicant/:id', {
        templateUrl : function(param) {
            return 'applicant';
        },
        controller : 'DashBoardCtrl'
    }).when('/register', {
        templateUrl : 'signup/create',
        controller : 'SignUpCtrl',
    }).when('/blog/create', {
        templateUrl : 'blog/create',
        controller : 'CreateBlogCtrl',
        resolve : {
            loggedin : checkLoggedin
        }
    }).when('/blog/:id', {
        templateUrl : function(param) {
            return 'blog';
        },
        controller : 'BlogCtrl'
    }).when('/poll/create', {
        templateUrl : 'poll/create',
        controller : 'CreatePollCtrl',
        resolve : {
            loggedin : checkLoggedin
        }
    }).when('/poll/:id', {
        templateUrl : function(param) {
            return 'poll';
        },
        controller : 'PollCtrl'
    }).when('/slideshow/create', {
        templateUrl : 'slideshow/create',
        controller : 'CreateSlideshowCtrl',
        resolve : {
            loggedin : checkLoggedin
        }
    }).when('/slideshow/:id', {
        templateUrl : function(param) {
            return 'slideshow';
        },
        controller : 'SlideshowCtrl'
    }).when('/profile/user/:id', {
        templateUrl : function(param) {
            return 'profile';
        },
        controller : 'ProfileCtrl'
    }).when('/blogs/:category/:type', {
        templateUrl : function(param) {
            return 'blogs';
        },
        controller : 'BlogsCtrl'
    }).when('/blogs/:category/latest', {
        templateUrl : function(param) {
            return 'blogs';
        },
        controller : 'BlogsCtrl'
    }).when('/blogs/:category/:subCategory/latest', {
        templateUrl : function(param) {
            return 'blogs/subView';
        },
        controller : 'BlogsCtrl'
    }).when('/polls/:category/latest', {
        templateUrl : function(param) {
            return 'polls/view';
        },
        controller : 'BlogsCtrl'
    }).when('/polls/:category/:subCategory/latest', {
        templateUrl : function(param) {
            return 'polls/subView';
        },
        controller : 'BlogsCtrl'
    }).when('/slideshows/:category/latest', {
        templateUrl : function(param) {
            return 'slideshows/view';
        },
        controller : 'BlogsCtrl'
    }).when('/slideshows/:category/:subCategory/latest', {
        templateUrl : function(param) {
            return 'slideshows/subView';
        },
        controller : 'BlogsCtrl'
    }).when('/tags/:tag/latest', {
        templateUrl : function(param) {
            return 'tags';
        },
        controller : 'TagsCtrl'
    }).when('/locations/:location/latest', {
        templateUrl : function(param) {
            return 'locations';
        },
        controller : 'LocationsCtrl'
    }).when('/locations/:location/popular', {
        templateUrl : function(param) {
            return 'locations';
        },
        controller : 'LocationsCtrl'
    }).when('/blogs/latest', {
        templateUrl : function(param) {
            return 'blogs';
        },
        controller : 'HomeCtrl'
    }).when('/blogs/todaylatest', {
        templateUrl : 'blogs/blogsTodayView',

        controller : 'HomeCtrl'
    }).when('/polls/latest', {
        templateUrl : 'polls/view',

        controller : 'HomeCtrl'
    }).when('/polls/todaylatest', {
        templateUrl : 'polls/pollsTodayView',

        controller : 'HomeCtrl'
    }).when('/slideshows/latest', {
        templateUrl : 'slideshows/view',
        controller : 'HomeCtrl'
    }).when('/slideshows/todaylatest', {
        templateUrl : 'slideshows/slideshowsTodayview',
        controller : 'HomeCtrl'
    }).when('/profile/page', {
        templateUrl : 'profile/page',
        controller : 'ProfileCtrl',
        resolve : {
            loggedin : checkLoggedin
        }
    }).when('/profile/allAccounts', {
        templateUrl : 'profile/allAccounts',
        controller : 'HomeCtrl'

    }).when('/profile/dashboard', {
        templateUrl : 'profile/dashboard',
        controller : 'DashBoardCtrl',
        resolve : {
            loggedin : checkLoggedin
        }
    }).when('/search/:type/:searchText', {
        templateUrl : function(param) {
            return 'search/' + param.type;
        },
        controller : 'SearchCtrl'
    }).when('/search/bylocations/:searchText', {
        templateUrl : function(param) {
            return 'search/bylocations';
        },
        controller : 'CommonCtrl'
    }).when('/technology', {
        templateUrl : 'public/technology',
        controller : 'BlogsCtrl',
        resolve : {
            loggedin : checkLoggedin
        }
    }).when('/settings', {
        templateUrl : function(param) {
            return 'settings';
        },
        controller : 'SettingsCtrl'
    }).when('/connect/facebook', {
        templateUrl : 'social/facebook',

        controller : 'SettingsCtrl'
    }).when('/blogsView', {
        templateUrl : 'blog/blogView',
        controller : 'BlogCtrl'

    }).when('/profile/palsbeats', {
        templateUrl : 'profile/palsbeats',
        controller : 'PalsCtrl',
        resolve : {
            loggedin : checkLoggedin
        }
    }).when('/allTags', {
        templateUrl : 'home/allTags',
        controller : 'HomeCtrl'

    }).when('/allLocations', {
        templateUrl : 'home/allLocations',
        controller : 'HomeCtrl'

    }).when('/blogs/byDate', {
        templateUrl : 'home/blogsByDate',
        controller : 'DateSearchCtrl'

    }).when('/polls/byDate', {
        templateUrl : 'home/pollsByDate',
        controller : 'DateSearchCtrl'

    }).when('/slideshows/byDate', {
        templateUrl : 'home/slideshowsByDate',
        controller : 'DateSearchCtrl'

    }).when('/settings/lock/:username', {
        templateUrl : 'settings/lockScreen',
        controller : 'LockScreenCtrl'

    }).otherwise({
        templateUrl : 'home',
        controller : 'HomeCtrl'
    });
    $provide.decorator('$sniffer', function($delegate) {
          $delegate.history = false;
          return $delegate;
        });



} ]).run(
        [ '$rootScope', '$location', 'Login',
                function($rootScope, $location, Login) {
                    $rootScope.loggedInUser = null;
                    $rootScope.currentDefaultAdd = '';
                    Login.getLoggedInUser(function(data) {
                        if (!data) {
                            $rootScope.loggedInUser = null;
                            $location.path('/home');
                        } else {
                            $rootScope.loggedInUser = data;
                        }
                    });

                } ]);
```

In index.jsp .I added 
When i run its displaying raw ..like below

```
Beats

Latest
Trending
Popular
View Beats
Blogs
Polls
Slideshow

Search
  Search


{{blog.category.name}}
Like
Share
Spam
{{blog.title}}

{{blog.creator.firstName}} {{blog.creator.lastName}}
{{blog.creationDate | date:'d MMMM yyyy'}}
{{blog.creationDate | timeago}}
{{blog.content | htmlToPlaintext}}

Read more
{{blog.defaultLocation.streetNumber}}{{blog.defaultLocation.street}}{{blog.defaultLocation.subLocality3}}{{blog.defaultLocation.subLocality2}}{{blog.defaultLocation.subLocality1}}{{blog.defaultLocation.city}} {{blog.defaultLocation.state}}{{blog.defaultLocation.zipcode}} {{blog.defaultLocation.country}}
```

Comment: Try adding $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); at the end of your routing code

Comment: You should check your browser console. There must be some javascript error showing.

Comment: No..no error showing in console

Comment: added at the end only still same problem

Comment: Try doing what @Kyoss has written in his answer i.e. add <base href="/"> as fallback option

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the

```
<base href="/">
```

to your HTML?

Comment: in index.jsp i added <base href="/blogbeats/">...and it work fine with this url http://localhost:8080/blogbeats/                                                                 But When refresh CSS and angularfiles not applying ..I added all files in index.jsp ...After refresh its not loading index.jsp ,loads home.jsp from serverside .i.e springcontroller